# Framework for a hello world application

Tags: accounts, assets, token, new-developer

Really simple question, with presumably involved answer:

I'm trying to understand how to make what starts off as a simple `hello_world` application where I sell the integers `"1-2-3..50"`
to `USER=account` who provides me `PRICE=n XLM` at contract `Z`.  This seems as simple as I can make it, but then it also suggests I'd like endpoints for:

1. `SELECT` who, which `USER`, has bought `asset=="1"`?
2. `LIST` which `asset`s have been bought?
3. `LIST` what assets has `USER=="x"` bought?
4. `SET PRICE=n*1.2` for future sales of integers.
5. `CREATE` a new asset, `"51"`, and make it available for sale.

I'm an experienced developer, but don't have a full appreciation for the toolchain and tradecraft/design patterns that go into this.

Does this mean I'm building only a contract?  Because by golly it already feels like a whole application.  Where does it modularize?

How much of this is something that the stellar chain/dev environment already gives?  If I /think/ this is all I need in my most minimal contract, what else do I need to consider too?

For example, it costs money to run the ops 1-5, right?  How do I set up the accounts that would receive these operations?  Also, to complicate slightly more, suppose I wanted to have privacy on some of these, or permissions on (5) to only allow `me=USER==0` to do this?

What are the best references for systematically understanding and correcting every foolish assumption I have above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the docs for Horizon](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/index.html), which is a RESTful API for gathering information about the network. It doesn't cost anything to make queries to it, but when building a real application, the best practice is to run your own Horizon instance to avoid centralization. Running Horizon implies running a core node, which has some nontrivial resource requirements, so it's not free in that regard.

You only pay fees for [transactions](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/transaction.html) (which contain [operations](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html)) submitted to the network. Stellar doesn't have smart contracts the same way Ethereum does—contracts don't run code, they're a sequence of transactions that are crafted in such a way that they provide guarantees about when they'll be valid.

To specifically address your questions:

- You can't query for accounts that own an asset. Assets list how many account holders there are ([`num_accounts` on the `/assets` endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/assets-all.html#response)), but the accounts can't be listed.
- Completed trades can be found under the [`/trades` endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/trades.html)
- Each account [lists which assets it trusts under the `balances` property](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/account.html#balances-object)
- You can't "set a price" for an asset to be sold at generally, but you can place a [sell offer](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/offer.html) listing a specific number of an asset for sale at a specific price. Maintaining liquidity for an asset means ensuring that there are buy/sell offers that others can cross.
- Creating a new asset isn't trivial, but it is simple to do for the basic case. [The docs have a page about it](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Ethereum, Stellar does not have automagic on chain contracts. You have to craft of chain transactions to achieve anything.

First read the [official guides](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/) and especially get familiar with the stellar ["transaction/contains operations"](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html) and [assets](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html) concepts.

Then as a first start, go to [stellar laboratory account creator](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test) where you can create as many testnet accounts as you want for free.

Play around with the [stellar laboratory transaction builder](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#txbuilder?network=test), create a simple native XLM payment transaction from one of your test accounts to another. Create an asset (create a trustline == how to set up accounts to receive...), create a payment with your asset.

You can also do all of this in a language of your choice with one of the [sdk](https://www.stellar.org/developers/reference/)s.